# Jenkins DSL : Job SLack publisher : baseUrl() method not available

Tags: jenkins, dsl, slack

I use Jenkins 2.63 with and Slack Notifier plugin 2.2

I need to generate Jobs with SlackNotifier by Job DSL but  I can not set the Base URL in the DSL, I get this message :

ERROR: (script, line 145) No signature of method: **baseUrl()** is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://my.domain.slack.com/services/hooks/jenkins-ci/] Possible solutions: authToken(), authTokenCredentialId(), botUser(), commitInfoChoice(), customMessage(), includeCustomMessage(), includeTestSummary(), notifyAborted(), notifyBackToNormal(), notifyFailure(), notifyNotBuilt(), notifyRegression(), notifyRepeatedFailure(), notifySuccess(), notifyUnstable(), room(), sendAs(), startNotification(), teamDomain() Finished: FAILURE

here is my DSL script

```
        publishers  {
          def slackParam = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File(channelFile))

          slackNotifier {
            baseUrl(slackParam.url)
            authTokenCredentialId(slackParam.authTokenCredentialId) 
            includeTestSummary(true) 
            notifyAborted(true) 
            notifyBackToNormal(true) 
            notifyFailure(true) 
            notifyNotBuilt(true) 
            notifyRegression(true) 
            notifyRepeatedFailure(true) 
            notifyUnstable(true)
            room(slackParam.room) 
          }
        }
```

But in the job config.xml I can find this parameter.

Can anyone help me to set the base URL parameter ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Configure Block: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block

```
  configure { project ->
    project / publishers << 'jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier' {
      baseUrl("https://whatever.slack.com/services/hooks/jenkins-ci/")
      room("#room")
      notifyAborted(true)
      notifyFailure(true)
      notifyNotBuilt(false)
      notifyUnstable(true)
      notifyBackToNormal(true)
      notifySuccess(true)
      notifyRepeatedFailure(false)
      startNotification(false)
      includeTestSummary(false)
      includeCustomMessage(true)
      customMessage("Environment")
      sendAs(null)
      commitInfoChoice("AUTHORS_AND_TITLES")
      teamDomain("yourDomain")
      authTokenCredentialId("token")
    }
  }
```

Place this outside of your steps at the bottom of your job. You should see the changes reflected in the UI and config.xml for the job.